# Find the max in a list of numbers using the for/while loop

Tags: python

Hi sorry can someone teach me how to find the max in a list of numbers using the for/while loop in python 3.  I have been stuck all day

for example

```
data = [73284, 8784.3, 9480938.2, 984958.3, 24131, 45789, 734987, 23545.3, 894859.2, 842758.3]
```

Comment: Show us the code you have made.

Comment: Also, any reason for not using max?

Comment: I am learning to use the loop functions. I have come across many different codes. But I cant figure out

Comment: data = [73284, 8784.3, 9480938.2, 984958.3, 24131, 45789, 734987, 23545.3, 894859.2, 842758.3]

for n in data:
      if n>



this is about all I got..

Comment: @JohnSSanders, see if  the answer if that helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use built-in function `max` in module builtins:

```
>>> data = [73284, 8784.3, 9480938.2, 984958.3, 24131, 45789, 734987, 23545.3, 894859.2, 842758.3]

>>> max(data)
9480938.2
```

**Info Page:**

> ```
> max(iterable, *[, default=obj, key=func]) -> value
> max(arg1, arg2, *args, *[, key=func]) -> value
>
> With a single iterable argument, return its biggest item. The
> default keyword-only argument specifies an object to return if
> the provided iterable is empty.
> With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
> ```

Just for the sake of for loop, but its not desirable..

```
>>> max_value = 0
>>> data = [73284, 8784.3, 9480938.2, 984958.3, 24131, 45789, 734987, 23545.3, 894859.2, 842758.3]
```

Foor loop to achieve it by setting the `max_value` to zero and then evaluate, you need to use `float` as your list has floating values not an integers.

```
#!python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
max_value = 0
data = [73284, 8784.3, 9480938.2, 984958.3, 24131, 45789, 734987, 23545.3, 894859.2, 842758.3]
for mx in data:
        if float(mx) > max_value: max_value = float(mx)
print("Highest Value From the List : " , (max_value))
```

Result:

```
$ ./max_val.py

Highest Value From the List :  9480938.2
```

Answer (score 1):

use the max() function. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

```
#!/usr/bin/python

data = [73284, 8784.3, 9480938.2, 984958.3, 24131, 45789, 734987, 23545.3, 894859.2, 842758.3]

print "Max value element : ", max(data)
```

Online Python Compiler
http://tpcg.io/puPnCl

For the looped version

First declare and populate the array.
Next declare and initialize the variable "highest" with 0
Then start the for loop as high feeding in the data array.
it will then loop through until the last number is the greatest in the array.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

data = [73284, 8784.3, 9480938.2, 984958.3, 24131, 45789, 734987, 23545.3, 894859.2, 842758.3]

highest = 0

for high in data:
    if highest < high:
        highest = high

print(highest)
```

Online Python Compiler
http://tpcg.io/VeeUk7